# How to make a windows slide out using WPF( expression Blend 4and C#)

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, expression-blend

I am trying to figure out how to connect windows so the slide out using a small button from the left or right of a main window.  What I am trying to do is create a main form with 2 windows connected to it.  For one of the windows when the user presses a button on the main window it makes the window seem to slide out rather than pop up. Here is where I got the idea http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVlSj0yr3rg&feature=related ..The user then changes a value and the main windows is updated with new information.  Honestly I have finished writing all my code and got everything working in Windows Forms in visual studio 2010 (with pop up windows).But I am thinking to make a more appealing gui WPF is the way to go, plus I like learning about it. If you have any forums, tutorials or general answers that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so judging from the video you really want some kind of expander that opens and not a Window.  A Window is an area with border, and the standard buttons and titlebar at the top.

This can be done with a grid with two columns.  One is set to Auto width, one is set to * width.  In the Auto sized one you can put your expanding content, and have your always visible content in the other.
The simple way to do this:

## The Xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="7"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="ExpandoGrid"/>
        <Button Content="..." Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="6" Height="40" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Grid x:Name="OtherContentGrid" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="-7,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## The Code-behind

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Class MainWindow

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        If Me.ExpandoGrid.Width = 7 Then Me.ExpandoGrid.Width = 200 Else Me.ExpandoGrid.Width = 7
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is by no means the complete way, or the best way. It is one of the simplest to implement though.  A better way would be with a ViewModel which would handle the state of the expanded area, along with some animations to make it a smooth transition.  If you want the sliding behaviour that is done in that video, animations are where it is at.  If you are using Blend, then you have the right tool for animations.

Personally I would have this Windows ViewModel have a property (lets call it DrawerExpanded as Boolean) that a customized Expander would bind its IsExpanded property to.  I would then create an open animation that sets the width of the content in the expander, and a close animation that sets the width to 0.  Additionally, in each of these I would probably include setting the visibility and opacity to make the effect better and not weird.  So lets say expand animation sets Width to 350 at .5 seconds, Visibility to visible at .5 seconds, and then opacity from 0 to 100 from .5 seconds to .7 seconds.  That way the drawer slides out and the content fades quickly into view.

If you want a code example of that, you may have to give me a few mins.

Answer (score 1):

I would really just take the easy/friendly route of creating `Visual States` in Expression Blend. There's basically just an "in state" and "out state", and an `InteractionTrigger` that allows the control to trigger the state change. Its awesome and extremely user friendly.

No code behind :) Hope it helps you!

As a bonus, you can easily add transition effects just like in a powerpoint. The xaml code gets pretty verbose, but working in Blend allows you to use the IDE to manage everything you add visually.

You can even use the `Interaction Trigger` to toggle between visibility states of the other controls, rather than writing `converters`, etc.